# Mathematica XML manipulation

Tags: xml, wolfram-mathematica

I have a literature database in XML and e.g. want to sort out the ones written in 2016. The data format is either **"{2016}"** oder **"{2016-xx-xx}"** and i want to select both. Following code only returns part of the relevant data.

```
y2016 = Cases[publications,
   XMLElement["eprint", _,
    {___, XMLElement["date", _, {"2016"}], ___}], Infinity];
```

Instead of the {"2016"} part i tried

```
{"2016"~~___}
{"2016"___}
{"2016",___}
```

This results only in the partial data or {}
How can i get a list of all publications written in 2016?

Comment: It's not possible to mix string patterns and expression patterns this way.  Change `"2016"` to `s_String /; StringStartsQ[s, "2016"]` or `s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "2016" ~~ ___]`.  BTW there's a dedicated site for Mathematica: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/